# Microsoft Surface 8 and Intune deployment

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

We’ve built a Windows app and we are trying to deploy it to Microsoft Intune. We’ve uploaded the app successfully but when we are trying to install it, it throws back an error — something to do with the signing certificate. I contacted Microsoft support multiple times now and each representative gave me a conflicting answer.

Some of them say it happens because we need to purchase a Symantec signing certificate and some say it’s because the devices we’re trying to deploy to are not Microsoft Enterprise. They can’t make their minds up and I thought someone here might know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I edited the tags to this question to remove the [tag:microsoft] tag, which should not be used, as stated in the tag wiki (though its continued existence is problematic in itself); this is further to the Meta question asked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293754/82548.